# How to time tigger a python script in the Azure ML notebooks

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-container-instances, azure-notebooks

Hi I am currently working on a small image classification project where the model classifies whether the image contains potholes or not. For this section i have wrote the python script, and this script needs to be triggered at scheduled time. I created a scheduled compute instance but the script doesn't get implemented when the compute instance is running. So i want to know what method should i use to get this sorted.

Comment: i guess this will work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-trigger-published-pipeline

Comment: Okay will check it out thank you

Answer (score 1):

Consider working your way through the Azure ML Pipelines guides (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-machine-learning-pipelines)

Once you have a pipeline you can schedule it using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-trigger-published-pipeline#create-a-schedule

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use compute instances for that - you should package your python code in a pipeline, make sure it is registered in the workspace, and then use the [schedule class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-core/azureml.pipeline.core.schedule(class)?view=azure-ml-py) on that pipeline.